# Missing Spring boot builder

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Eclipse is not updating the class files of my current project. After reading a couple of posts here I checked Builders for the project. where I found this message:

**Missing builder (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.validation.springbootbuilder)**
Any idea why this is happening?

Maven is also used in this project, Don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), "Missing builder", sounds like a "missing plugin"(!?)

"Try these", please:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4
- (resp.) https://spring.io/tools